# How to open a url that redirects to a application with python

Tags: python, url, redirect

There is a url when opened on android, redirects to a certain application. I don't need to actually open the application but only simulate(?) opening it. Is there a header or requests that I can use for this? I'm preety sure this is not possible with python, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to catch the redirected url from the HTTP response ?

Comment: nope I meant that I wanted to use headers to make it look like I was opening the link from an application